# shadowed border change color doesn't work java

Tags: java, graphics2d

I found 2 examples about shadow-border in the internet.
For one example, which I want to use, I can't change the color.
Here is the code, where the color is defined:

```
private Map<Position,BufferedImage> getImages(Graphics2D g2) {
    //first, check to see if an image for this size has already been rendered
    //if so, use the cache. Else, draw and save

    Map<Position,BufferedImage> images = CACHE.get(shadowSize);
    if (images == null) {
        images = new HashMap<Position,BufferedImage>();

        int rectWidth = cornerSize + 1;
        int imageWidth = rectWidth + shadowSize * 2;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                imageWidth, imageWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D buffer = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        buffer.setColor(new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f));
        buffer.translate(shadowSize, shadowSize);
        RoundRectangle2D rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
                0, 0, rectWidth, rectWidth, cornerSize, cornerSize);
        buffer.fill(rect);
        buffer.dispose();

        float blurry = 1.0f / (float)(shadowSize * shadowSize);
        float[] blurKernel = new float[shadowSize * shadowSize];
        for (int i=0; i<blurKernel.length; i++) {
            blurKernel[i] = blurry;
        }
        ConvolveOp blur = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(shadowSize, shadowSize, blurKernel));
        BufferedImage targetImage = new BufferedImage(
                imageWidth, imageWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) targetImage.getGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(
                image, blur, -(shadowSize/2), -(shadowSize/2));

        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int w = shadowSize;
        int h = shadowSize;
        images.put(Position.TOP_LEFT, getSubImage(targetImage, x, y, w,  h));
 // and so on...
 }
```

Edit:

```
public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics graphics, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

      Map<Position,BufferedImage> images = getImages(null);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)graphics.create();
      g2.setColor(Color.red);

    Point topLeftShadowPoint = null;
    if (showLeftShadow || showTopShadow) {
        topLeftShadowPoint = new Point();
        if (showLeftShadow && !showTopShadow) {
            topLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y + height - shadowSize);
        } else if (showLeftShadow && showTopShadow) {
            topLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y + height - shadowSize);
        } else if (!showLeftShadow && showTopShadow) {
            topLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y + height - shadowSize);
        }
    }

    Point bottomRightShadowPoint = null;
    if (showRightShadow || showBottomShadow) {
        bottomRightShadowPoint = new Point();
        if (showRightShadow && !showBottomShadow) {
            bottomRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x, y );
        } else if (showRightShadow && showBottomShadow) {
            bottomRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x, y);
        } else if (!showRightShadow && showBottomShadow) {
            bottomRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x , y);
        }
    }

    Point bottomLeftShadowPoint = null;
    if (showLeftShadow || showBottomShadow) {
        bottomLeftShadowPoint = new Point();
        if (showLeftShadow && !showBottomShadow) {
            bottomLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y );
        } else if (showLeftShadow && showBottomShadow) {
            bottomLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y);
        } else if (!showLeftShadow && showBottomShadow) {
            bottomLeftShadowPoint.setLocation(x + width - shadowSize, y);
        }
    }

    Point topRightShadowPoint = null;
    if (showRightShadow || showTopShadow) {
        topRightShadowPoint = new Point();
        if (showRightShadow && !showTopShadow) {
            topRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x, y + height - shadowSize);
        } else if (showRightShadow && showTopShadow) {
            topRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x, y + height - shadowSize);
        } else if (!showRightShadow && showTopShadow) {
            topRightShadowPoint.setLocation(x, y + height - shadowSize);
        }
    }

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    if (showRightShadow) {
        Rectangle leftShadowRect =
            new Rectangle(x + width - shadowSize,
                    topRightShadowPoint.y + shadowSize,
                    shadowSize,
                    bottomRightShadowPoint.y - topRightShadowPoint.y - shadowSize);

        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.LEFT),
                     leftShadowRect.x, leftShadowRect.y,
                     leftShadowRect.width, leftShadowRect.height, null);
    }

    if (showLeftShadow) {
        Rectangle rightShadowRect =
            new Rectangle(x,
                    topLeftShadowPoint.y + shadowSize,
                    shadowSize,
                    bottomLeftShadowPoint.y - topLeftShadowPoint.y - shadowSize);            
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.RIGHT),
                     rightShadowRect.x, rightShadowRect.y,
                     rightShadowRect.width, rightShadowRect.height, null);
    }


    if (showTopShadow) {
        Rectangle bottomShadowRect =
            new Rectangle(topLeftShadowPoint.x + shadowSize,
                    y,
                    topRightShadowPoint.x - topLeftShadowPoint.x - shadowSize,
                    shadowSize);

        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.BOTTOM),
                     bottomShadowRect.x, bottomShadowRect.y,
                     bottomShadowRect.width, bottomShadowRect.height, null);
    }


    if (showBottomShadow) {
        Rectangle topShadowRect =
            new Rectangle(bottomLeftShadowPoint.x + shadowSize,
                    y + height - shadowSize,
                    bottomRightShadowPoint.x - bottomLeftShadowPoint.x - shadowSize,
                    shadowSize);            
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.TOP),
                     topShadowRect.x, topShadowRect.y,
                     topShadowRect.width, topShadowRect.height, null);
    }

   if (showLeftShadow || showTopShadow) {
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.TOP_LEFT),
                     topLeftShadowPoint.x, topLeftShadowPoint.y, null);
    }
    if (showLeftShadow || showBottomShadow) {
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.BOTTOM_LEFT),
                     bottomLeftShadowPoint.x, bottomLeftShadowPoint.y, null);
    }
    if (showRightShadow || showBottomShadow) {
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.BOTTOM_RIGHT),
                     bottomRightShadowPoint.x, bottomRightShadowPoint.y, null);
    }
    if (showRightShadow || showTopShadow) {
        g2.drawImage(images.get(Position.TOP_RIGHT),
                     topRightShadowPoint.x, topRightShadowPoint.y, null);
    }

    g2.dispose();
    }
```

I choosed: new Color( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f), which should show a red border. But the gray border comes, too.
Has anybody a suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you could post a image so I can get a better idea of what you mean by both colors show up? Curious about this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider instead using the ShadowBorder class that has predefined classes and would make what your trying to achieve MUCH easier, I'm not sure if this is already what your using but

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/ui/border/ShadowBorder.html

is the link to the API. You could use the method for both paintBorder as well as setColor to ensure that only the color you want shows.

Comment: Do I have to download the full Oracle JDeveloper, or is it enough to download the Generic Release Java Edition and how is the jar file called?

Comment: You would need to download Developer. It would be a bit of a pain but it is very useful to have as Oracle has some unique tools that would be at your disposal. I believe you would have to add the entire Middlewear Extension after that which I've not done before but I'm sure there are directions on the oracle site.

Comment: The ShadowBorder has a method setColor, but it ignores the Color and shows a gray border, too.